# Error(15,5): PLS-00103 while saving the stored procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have written a stored procedure which would pull the counts from tables and if there is any mismatch in counts some sql query will be executed to capture the missed item. The output of the stored procedure is logged into the .txt file using utl_file.

I am receiving error when I try to compile the procedure.

Note: I have checked other posts related to this error, but I am unable to figure out what went wrong as I am just learning PL-SQL. Please suggest me the corrections required in the code.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE           "PROC_TOTAL_EVENTS"
AS

file_handle      utl_file.file_type; 
utl_dir          VARCHAR2(255) := '/u01/apps/Miscellaneous/bin'
counts             NUMBER;
counts1            NUMBER;
counts2            NUMBER;
counts3            NUMBER;
missed_a           NUMBER;
missed_b           NUMBER;
missed_c           VARCHAR2(50); 
retrieved_buffer VARCHAR2(100);

BEGIN
file_handle := utl_file.fopen(utl_dir,'spool.txt','W');
dbms_output.put_line('File opened for write');

utl_file.put_line(file_handle, 'Executing the counts for total_events');
dbms_output.put_line('--------------------------------');


select /*+ PARALLEL(PH,8)) */ count(*) into counts from 
cdb_admin.CPM_PREF_EVENT_STG;
utl_file.putf(file_handle, 'Total preference events sent to CPM from CDB', 
counts);
dbms_output.put_line('1 step success');

SELECT COUNT(distinct cdb_pref_event_id) into counts1 FROM 
cdb_admin.cpm_pref_result WHERE
cdb_pref_event_id IN (SELECT /*+ PARALLEL(PH,8)) */ cdb_pref_event_id FROM
cdb_admin.CPM_PREF_EVENT_STG ph;
utl_file.putf(file_handle, 'distinct count of total prefResults sent 
by CPM to CDB', counts1);
dbms_output.put_line('2 step success');

Select count(distinct e.cdb_pref_event_id) Total_exception_count into 
counts from 
(Select distinct eh.cdb_customer_id cdb_customer_id,eh.cdb_pref_event_id 
cdb_pref_event_id,eh.supp_cd supp_cd 
from cdb_admin.CPM_PREF_EVENT_STG eh Left outer join  
CDB_ADMIN.CPM_PREF_RESULT er on (eh.cdb_customer_id=er.cdb_customer_id and 
eh.cdb_pref_event_id=er.cdb_pref_event_id)
where er.cdb_pref_event_id is null and er.cdb_customer_id is null) r  join 
CDB_ADMIN.cpm_pref_event_exception e 
on (r.cdb_customer_id=e.cdb_customer_id and 
r.cdb_pref_event_id=e.cdb_pref_event_id) where e.supp_cd != 'PROFILE-NOT- 
FOUND';
utl_file.putf(file_handle, 'distinct count of total exceptions sent by CPM 
to CDB', counts2);
dbms_output.put_line('3 step success');

Select count(distinct e.cdb_pref_event_id),e.supp_cd from 
(Select distinct eh.cdb_customer_id cdb_customer_id,eh.cdb_pref_event_id 
cdb_pref_event_id,eh.supp_cd supp_cd 
from (select * from cdb_admin.CPM_PREF_EVENT_STG) eh Left outer join  
CDB_ADMIN.CPM_PREF_RESULT er on (eh.cdb_customer_id=er.cdb_customer_id and 
eh.cdb_pref_event_id=er.cdb_pref_event_id)
where er.cdb_pref_event_id is null and er.cdb_customer_id is null) r  join 
CDB_ADMIN.cpm_pref_event_exception e 
on (r.cdb_customer_id=e.cdb_customer_id and 
r.cdb_pref_event_id=e.cdb_pref_event_id)  group by e.supp_cd;
utl_file.putf(file_handle, 'Counts bifurcation', counts3);
dbms_output.put_line('4 step success'); 


IF counts = (counts1+counts2) THEN
  utl_file.putf(file_handle, 'Counts are matching', counts, 
  (counts1+counts2));
ELSE
  dbms_output.put_line('Counts are not matching, finding the missed 
  record'); 
  SELECT DISTINCT r.cdb_customer_id, r.cdb_pref_event_id,r.supp_cd into 
  missed_a,missed_b,missed_c
   FROM
   (
       SELECT DISTINCT
        eh.cdb_customer_id cdb_customer_id,
        eh.cdb_pref_event_id cdb_pref_event_id,
        eh.supp_cd supp_cd
    FROM
        (select * from cdb_admin.CPM_PREF_EVENT_STG eh
        LEFT OUTER JOIN cdb_admin.cpm_pref_result er ON ( 
  eh.cdb_customer_id = er.cdb_customer_id
                                                          AND 
  eh.cdb_pref_event_id = er.cdb_pref_event_id )
    WHERE
        er.cdb_pref_event_id IS NULL
        AND   er.cdb_customer_id IS NULL
    ) r
    LEFT OUTER JOIN cdb_admin.cpm_pref_event_exception e ON ( 
    r.cdb_customer_id = e.cdb_customer_id
    AND r.cdb_pref_event_id = e.cdb_pref_event_id ) WHERE 
    e.cdb_pref_event_id IS NULL AND   e.cdb_customer_id IS NULL;
utl_file.putf(file_handle, 'missed record ID and country code', 
    missed_a,missed_b,missed_c);
END IF;

utl_file.fclose(file_handle);
dbms_output.put_line('File closed');

file_handle := utl_file.fopen(utl_dir,'TotEvents.txt','R');
dbms_output.put_line('File opened for read');

utl_file.get_line(file_handle, retrieved_buffer);
dbms_output.put_line('Read success');

dbms_output.put_line(retrieved_buffer);

utl_file.fclose(file_handle);
dbms_output.put_line('File closed');
EXCEPTION
   WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
   ROLLBACK;
   RAISE;
   dbms_output.put_line('No Data Found : Exception');
   dbms_output.put_line('Errorcode: ' || sqlcode || ' Error message: ' || sqlerrm);

   WHEN TOO_MANY_ROWS THEN
   ROLLBACK;
   RAISE;
   dbms_output.put_line('Too Many Rows : Exception');
   dbms_output.put_line('Errorcode: ' || sqlcode || ' Error message: ' || sqlerrm);

   WHEN OTHERS THEN
   ROLLBACK;
   RAISE;
   dbms_output.put_line('Others : Eception');
   dbms_output.put_line('Errorcode: ' || sqlcode || ' Error message: ' || sqlerrm);
END;
```

Error Details:

> Error(15,5): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "COUNTS" when expecting one of the following: * & = - + ; < / > at in is mod remainder not rem <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like like2 like4 likec between || multiset member submultiset

Comment: You missed the `semicolon(;)` at the end of the line `utl_dir          VARCHAR2(255) := '/u01/apps/Miscellaneous/bin'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3 errors as far as formatting is concerned - one missing semi-colon, two missing closing parenthesis. I marked them with comments; have a look.

As of exception handling section: once you `RAISE` the error, nothing is being executed so you won't see anything you wanted to (i.e. no `dbms_output` will ever be run). Basically, as you aren't *handling* anything, you can omit the whole section. Any error will be raised by Oracle anyway.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "PROC_TOTAL_EVENTS"
AS
   file_handle       UTL_FILE.file_type;
   utl_dir           VARCHAR2 (255) := '/u01/apps/Miscellaneous/bin';  --> mising semi-colon
   counts            NUMBER;
   counts1           NUMBER;
   counts2           NUMBER;
   counts3           NUMBER;
   missed_a          NUMBER;
   missed_b          NUMBER;
   missed_c          VARCHAR2 (50);
   retrieved_buffer  VARCHAR2 (100);
BEGIN
   file_handle := UTL_FILE.fopen (utl_dir, 'spool.txt', 'W');
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('File opened for write');

   UTL_FILE.put_line (file_handle, 'Executing the counts for total_events');
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('--------------------------------');


   SELECT /*+ PARALLEL(PH,8)) */
         COUNT (*) INTO counts FROM cdb_admin.CPM_PREF_EVENT_STG;

   UTL_FILE.putf (file_handle,
                  'Total preference events sent to CPM from CDB',
                  counts);
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('1 step success');

   SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT cdb_pref_event_id)
     INTO counts1
     FROM cdb_admin.cpm_pref_result
    WHERE cdb_pref_event_id IN (SELECT /*+ PARALLEL(PH,8)) */
                                       cdb_pref_event_id
                                  FROM cdb_admin.CPM_PREF_EVENT_STG ph);   --> missing closing parenthesis

   UTL_FILE.putf (file_handle,
                  'distinct count of total prefResults sent 
    by CPM to CDB',
                  counts1);
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('2 step success');

   SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT e.cdb_pref_event_id) Total_exception_count
     INTO counts
     FROM (SELECT DISTINCT
                  eh.cdb_customer_id cdb_customer_id,
                  eh.cdb_pref_event_id cdb_pref_event_id,
                  eh.supp_cd supp_cd
             FROM cdb_admin.CPM_PREF_EVENT_STG eh
                  LEFT OUTER JOIN CDB_ADMIN.CPM_PREF_RESULT er
                     ON (    eh.cdb_customer_id = er.cdb_customer_id
                         AND eh.cdb_pref_event_id = er.cdb_pref_event_id)
            WHERE     er.cdb_pref_event_id IS NULL
                  AND er.cdb_customer_id IS NULL) r
          JOIN CDB_ADMIN.cpm_pref_event_exception e
             ON (    r.cdb_customer_id = e.cdb_customer_id
                 AND r.cdb_pref_event_id = e.cdb_pref_event_id)
    WHERE e.supp_cd != 'PROFILE-NOT- 
    FOUND';

   UTL_FILE.putf (file_handle,
                  'distinct count of total exceptions sent by CPM 
    to CDB',
                  counts2);
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('3 step success');

     SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT e.cdb_pref_event_id), e.supp_cd
       FROM (SELECT DISTINCT
                    eh.cdb_customer_id cdb_customer_id,
                    eh.cdb_pref_event_id cdb_pref_event_id,
                    eh.supp_cd supp_cd
               FROM (SELECT * FROM cdb_admin.CPM_PREF_EVENT_STG) eh
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN CDB_ADMIN.CPM_PREF_RESULT er
                       ON (    eh.cdb_customer_id = er.cdb_customer_id
                           AND eh.cdb_pref_event_id = er.cdb_pref_event_id)
              WHERE     er.cdb_pref_event_id IS NULL
                    AND er.cdb_customer_id IS NULL) r
            JOIN CDB_ADMIN.cpm_pref_event_exception e
               ON (    r.cdb_customer_id = e.cdb_customer_id
                   AND r.cdb_pref_event_id = e.cdb_pref_event_id)
   GROUP BY e.supp_cd;

   UTL_FILE.putf (file_handle, 'Counts bifurcation', counts3);
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('4 step success');


   IF counts = (counts1 + counts2)
   THEN
      UTL_FILE.putf (file_handle,
                     'Counts are matching',
                     counts,
                     (counts1 + counts2));
   ELSE
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Counts are not matching, finding the missed 
      record');

      SELECT DISTINCT r.cdb_customer_id, r.cdb_pref_event_id, r.supp_cd
        INTO missed_a, missed_b, missed_c
        FROM (SELECT DISTINCT
                     eh.cdb_customer_id cdb_customer_id,
                     eh.cdb_pref_event_id cdb_pref_event_id,
                     eh.supp_cd supp_cd
                FROM (SELECT *
                        FROM cdb_admin.CPM_PREF_EVENT_STG eh
                             LEFT OUTER JOIN cdb_admin.cpm_pref_result er
                                ON (    eh.cdb_customer_id =
                                           er.cdb_customer_id
                                    AND eh.cdb_pref_event_id =
                                           er.cdb_pref_event_id)
                       WHERE     er.cdb_pref_event_id IS NULL
                             AND er.cdb_customer_id IS NULL) r
                     LEFT OUTER JOIN cdb_admin.cpm_pref_event_exception e
                        ON (    r.cdb_customer_id = e.cdb_customer_id
                            AND r.cdb_pref_event_id = e.cdb_pref_event_id)
               WHERE     e.cdb_pref_event_id IS NULL
                     AND e.cdb_customer_id IS NULL);                       --> missing closing parenthesis

      UTL_FILE.putf (file_handle,
                     'missed record ID and country code',
                     missed_a,
                     missed_b,
                     missed_c);
   END IF;

   UTL_FILE.fclose (file_handle);
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('File closed');

   file_handle := UTL_FILE.fopen (utl_dir, 'TotEvents.txt', 'R');
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('File opened for read');

   UTL_FILE.get_line (file_handle, retrieved_buffer);
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Read success');

   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (retrieved_buffer);

   UTL_FILE.fclose (file_handle);
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('File closed');
EXCEPTION
   WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
   THEN
      ROLLBACK;
      RAISE;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('No Data Found : Exception');
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (
         'Errorcode: ' || SQLCODE || ' Error message: ' || SQLERRM);
   WHEN TOO_MANY_ROWS
   THEN
      ROLLBACK;
      RAISE;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Too Many Rows : Exception');
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (
         'Errorcode: ' || SQLCODE || ' Error message: ' || SQLERRM);
   WHEN OTHERS
   THEN
      ROLLBACK;
      RAISE;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Others : Eception');
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (
         'Errorcode: ' || SQLCODE || ' Error message: ' || SQLERRM);
END;
```